# JS map return object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I got this array,

```
const rockets = [
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
];
```

What do I need to do in order to return an array mapped, that adds 10 to each `launches` value.

Here's my first approach:

```
const launchOptimistic = rockets.map(function(elem){
     return (elem.country, elem.launches+10);
});
console.log(launchOptimistic);
```

Comment: Do you want to alter the original objects? Or do you want to create new objects (copies)?

Comment: return array similar can be new

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Use .map without return in simple way. Also start using let and const instead of var because let and const is more recommended

```js
const rockets = [
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
];

const launchOptimistic = rockets.map(elem => (
  {
    country: elem.country,
    launches: elem.launches+10
  } 
));

console.log(launchOptimistic);
```

Comment: Just one question: why are rounded paretheses around the returned object necessary? Why can't that lambda just return the object like this:
`const launchOptimistic = rockets.map(elem => 
  {
    country: elem.country,
    launches: elem.launches+10
  } 
);`
?

Comment: Rounded parenthesis is used to return statements with multi line.

Comment: @Iorweth333 because the syntax `() => {}` uses braces to declare a function body, so instead of returning an object, it would actually try to evaluate the contents of the braces as a function, and throw syntax errors.

Answer (score 63):

You're very close already, you just need to return the new object that you want. In this case, the same one except with the launches value incremented by 10:

```js
const rockets = [
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
];

const launchOptimistic = rockets.map(function(elem) {
  return {
    country: elem.country,
    launches: elem.launches+10,
  } 
});

console.log(launchOptimistic);
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to alter the original objects, then a simple `Array#forEach` will do:

```
rockets.forEach(function(rocket) {
    rocket.launches += 10;
});
```

If you want to keep the original objects unaltered, then use `Array#map` and copy the objects using `Object#assign`:

```
const newRockets = rockets.map(function(rocket) {
    const newRocket = Object.assign({}, rocket);
    newRocket.launches += 10;
    return newRocket;
});
```

Comment: You meant to use `map` in the second example instead the `forEach`?

Answer (score 11):

The cleanest solution is destructuring.

```
const rockets = [
        { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
        { country:'US', launches:23 },
        { country:'China', launches:16 },
        { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
        { country:'India', launche`enter code here`s:4 },
        { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
    ];
    const updated = rockets.map(rocket=>{
    return {...rocket,launches:rocket.launches+10}
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

`map` rockets and add 10 to its launches:

```js
const rockets = [
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
];
rockets.map((itm) => {
    itm.launches += 10
    return itm
})
console.log(rockets)
```

If you don't want to modify `rockets` you can do:

```
var plusTen = []
rockets.forEach((itm) => {
    plusTen.push({'country': itm.country, 'launches': itm.launches + 10})
})
```

Comment: [CRice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6293409/crice) noted that this will mutate the items in the original array, which was rejected to be included into the answer. Please consider that I am not this user, I just wanted to give the credit.

Answer (score 4):

Considering objects can have many properties,
It would be better to spread the object's content and to reassign specific properties, to achieve code that is more succinct.

```js
const rockets = [
    { country:'Russia', launches:32 },
    { country:'US', launches:23 },
    { country:'China', launches:16 },
    { country:'Europe(ESA)', launches:7 },
    { country:'India', launches:4 },
    { country:'Japan', launches:3 }
];

const launchOptimistic = rockets.map(function(elem) {
  return {
    ...elem,
    launches: elem.launches+10,
  } 
});

console.log(launchOptimistic);
```

Answer (score 4):

### Solution (One Liner) With a Fresh Example

Suppose the clients in your bank (including you, of course) got a bonus.

```
let finance = [
    {funds:10050, client_id: 1020},
    {funds:25000, client_id: 77},
    {funds:90000, client_id: 442}
];

finance = finance.map(({funds, client_id}) => {funds = funds + 2000; return {funds, client_id}});
```

*↑ Test & copy as is to Chrome / Firefox / Edge [DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) console ↑*

This technique called [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
> makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
> objects, into distinct variables.

Answer (score 4):

Funny how every single solution relies on heavy funcitons and `return`s, except the one that uses an external accumulator, resembling more a `reduce` or a `forEach`. In any case, this subverts the original intention of the `map` and, in fact, of all Functional Programming: say *what*, not *how*. And yes, `map` *is* Functional Programming!

Here's a thought:

```js
const rockets = [
    { country: 'Russia', launches: 32 },
    { country: 'US', launches: 23 },
    { country: 'China', launches: 16 },
    { country: 'Europe(ESA)', launches: 7 },
    { country: 'India', launches: 4 },
    { country: 'Japan', launches: 3 }
]

const updated = rockets.map( rocket => ({...rocket, launches: rocket.launches + 10}) )
```

Please notice that:

1. This is a true one-liner because it does not use `return`. (cf. [Emre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7643635/emre)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69493480/2571805), [Stas Sorokin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142480/stas-sorokin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70604979/2571805) or [nir segev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3405194/nir-segev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69512925/2571805).) The trick is the parenthesis around the result object. Without these, the syntax will "think" you're going for a code block and expect statements instead of expressions, and a `return` at the end.
2. This does not change the original object ([Nir Alfasi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057429/nir-alfasi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47841916/2571805)) or uses global state ([vera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/vera)'s edit)
3. This uses destructured assignment, which is something many answers use, but funny enough, is explicitly mentioned in [Stas Sorokin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142480/stas-sorokin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70604979/2571805), with the link to MDN and all. Dear Stas, foillow your own link, because your answer does **NOT** use destructured assignment **AT ALL**!
4. This answer also fixes formatting because I was not raised by wolves. You have your spaces after commas and colons, you don't have useless semicolons because they only make sense in minified JS and webpack does that for you, and you don't have double tabs for single structure nesting (like [Emre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7643635/emre)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69493480/2571805)), because that's just flat out *fugly* and almost as bad as no indentation at all.